# How should I disable variable font sizes globally

Tags: spacemacs, fonts

I'm aware of several answers regarding font sizes for org or auctex. However, is there a way to require all faces have the default font size for all modes? I'm new to emacs and currently using spacemacs. I'm happy with whatever solutions works, but I'd prefer a solution that only involves editing `.spacemacs`as I'm reluctant to poke around in other config files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the *best* way to do it, but you can loop over all faces and set their height to 1.0, which means to use the same height as the default face:

```
(cl-loop for face in (face-list) do
         (unless (eq face 'default)
           (set-face-attribute face nil :height 1.0)))
```

I think this won't affect faces created after the loop runs, so it may need to be run again after loading more packages. (Maybe `after-load-functions`, or if it's just a few packages creating these faces, `with-eval-after-load` on those packages)